# Заполнить массив случайными объектами

Tags: java, массивы, объекты

Есть 3 класса Car, Bycicle и Bike; Нужно заполнить массив из 10 ячеек случайными объектами этих классов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не обязательно наследовать классы от какого-то общего класса: все они наследуют `Object`.
Самый простой вариант (не самый лучший с точки зрения практического использования, но хорошо решающий поставленную задачу):

```
public static Object[] fill() {
    Object[] array = new Object[10];
    Object obj = null;
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int randomNumber = randomizer.nextInt(3);
        switch(randomNumber) {
            case 0:
                obj = new Car();
                break;
            case 1:
                obj = new Bicycle();   
                break;
            case 2:
                obj = new Bike();      
                break;
        }
        array[i] = obj;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Метод для проверки:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Object o:fill()) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
```

Вывод на экран (классы у меня вложенные в класс `ComplexNumber`):

> com.company.ComplexNumber$Bicycle@677327b6
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bike@14ae5a5
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Car@7f31245a
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Car@6d6f6e28
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bike@135fbaa4
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bike@45ee12a7
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bicycle@330bedb4
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bicycle@2503dbd3
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bike@4b67cf4d
>   com.company.ComplexNumber$Bicycle@7ea987ac

Видно, что массив заполнен объектами разных классов.

Answer (score 2):

В каждом классе есть поля, которые сводятся к примитивным типам в итоге. Вам нужно для каждого поля класса, если это примитив, то сгенерировать его, если не примитив, генерировать примитивы, из которых состоит этот объект. И так далее. Полагаю, что у вас полей немного совсем и это будет несложно. Как генерировать случайную строку, можно посмотруть например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863852/how-to-generate-a-random-string-in-java). Если вам нужна случайная строка или значение из какого-то набора, то обычно заносят этот набор в какую-нибудь переменную, а затем выбирают значение из набора по случайно сгенерированному индексу.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте класс `Vehicle` c общими атрибутами от уже имеющихся классов. Унаследуйте `Car` , `Bycicle` и `Bike` от `Vehicle`.

Создайте метод в классе `Vehicle` метод `rand`, где по некоторому условию будет производиться выделении памяти того или иного класса-наследника.

Создайте массив `Vehicle` и в цикле заново выделяйте память.

---

#### Пример

Класс `Car`:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    Car(){
        super(200);
    };
}
```

Класс `Bike`:

```
public class Bike extends Vehicle {
   Bike(){
      super(80);
   }
}
```

Класс `Vehicle`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Vehicle {
    int maxSpeed;

    Vehicle(int m ){
        this.maxSpeed=m;
    }

    static public Vehicle rand(){
        Random rand= new Random();
        Vehicle v;
        if (rand.nextBoolean())
            v = new Car();
        else
            v= new Bike();
        return v;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v[] = new Vehicle[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            v[i]=Vehicle.rand();
            System.out.println(i+" "+v[i].maxSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

> [0-200] 
>    [1-80] 
>    [2-80] 
>    [3-200] 
>    [4-200] 
>    [5-80] 
>    [6-200] 
>    [7-80] 
>    [8-200] 
>    [9-80]